# Is it possible to configure prettier to have individual settings for vue SFC blocks

Tags: prettier, vue-sfc

I'm working on a code base that has

- tabwidth 2 for html/XML and CSS content
- tabwidth 4 for js/ts content

consequently In vue SFC files there is tabwidth 2 in the template section, and tabwidth 4 in the script section.
Is it possible to configure prettier to comply with this convention?

I know I can do [config overrides](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration#configuration-overrides), but I can only see that it is possible to specify filters for entire files there.
[related guthub discusssion](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/discussions/15536)